# Need help dealing with repeated SPAMHAUS listings at small company

Tags: server, spam

Setup: We have a mail server running exchange 2010 and a windows server 2011 for active directory. We also have a draytek router. I have access to all these things just not super familiar.

I work for a company as a junior IT tech so I have not set any of this up but need to find a solution. We're getting added to the spamhaus blocklist every other week or so.

What i've tried so far:

I have scanned the 30 computers with about 5 different virus scanners and mostly found minor things with malwarebytes which have been removed but we keep getting listed.

Also tried running netstat on each PC to monitor port 25 connections but none of the PC's checked seemed to be sending out of this port.

I have access to the router and can login to it and have heard about blocking port 25 but whenever I do this no one can send emails out. On the dreytek syslogs I can see an IP address from a virtual server that is 190.2.141.250 connecting to our main server on port 25 (SMPT). I suspect this is the thing that is sending out the spam but I can't find out how to block it.

I am kinda lost so any ideas would be appreciated